# Can't get CtrlP to set working dir as root folder

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Im working on project that is in fact composed of several subproject, under a common git repository:

```
Project
   - Sub Project A
   - Sub Project B
   - ...
```

I never work on the main folder, and always start from one of the sub projects, the problem is no matter what I try CtrlP always does the search starting from the main folder where the repo is.

I've tried a few settings from the project repo but no matter, such as bellow, but still can't get it to make any effect.

`let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ca'`

Any tips please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [CtrlP docs](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt) suggests that you have three options:

1. Disable CtrlP's working directory searching: `let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = ''`. It will then only search under Vim's current working directory, so just `:cd` to one of your sub projects' directories.
2. Ignore the sub project directories that you are not interested in: `let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = { 'dir': '\v[\/]Sub Project [AB]$' }` (*untested*).
3. Add *Sub Project A*, *Sub Project B*, etc. as root markers: `let g:ctrlp_root_markers = ['Sub Project A', 'Sub Project B']`. This should stop CtrlP from traversing up beyond those sub directories.

I would suggest the first option since the others are a bit too hacky for my taste. The last option also didn't work for me in a quick test.

Comment: Cool, I can now have search to be a bit more useful, just need to massage the ignore thing now.
The first option was enough for I was looking after. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to CtrlP starting in your current working directory, and it suddenly seems to have stopped, it's probably a side effect of `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode` that is a bit unintuitive: it searches up the directory tree until it finds a source control root (like a `.git` folder), and treats that as the top level directory.

I'm used to it always being the top level of my current project, so when I started a new project, and it was using my home directory as the root, I was confused. It's because I hadn't yet initialized Git for the new project, so the first `.git` directory it found was in my home directory.

Initializing a Git repo for the new project made it behave as expected.

Here's the relevant section of the plugin help:

> ```
>                                                 'g:ctrlp_working_path_mode'
> ```
>
> When starting up, CtrlP sets its local working directory according to this
>     variable:
>       let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
>
> ```
> c - the directory of the current file.
> a - like "c", but only applies when the current working directory outside of
>     CtrlP isn't a direct ancestor of the directory of the current file.
> r - the nearest ancestor that contains one of these directories or files:
>     .git .hg .svn .bzr _darcs
> w - begin finding a root from the current working directory outside of CtrlP
>     instead of from the directory of the current file (default). Only applies
>     when "r" is also present.
> 0 or <empty> - disable this feature.
> ```
>
> Note #1: if "a" or "c" is included with "r", use the behavior of "a" or "c" (as
>     a fallback) when a root can't be found.
>
> Note #2: you can use a b:var to set this option on a per buffer basis.